# How to move from one Panel to another in a single frame without using CardLayout?

Tags: java, jpanel

I have three Panels and a single Frame in my program. I want to close/hide the current panel and show/activate the next panel. I am designing a game, hence I do not want to use `CardLayout`.

```
private void select() {
    if (currentChoice == 0) {
        f.remove(gpanel1);
        gpanel = new GamePanel();
        f.add(gpanel);
    }
}
```

Here `f` is the frame object. `gpanel1` and `gpanel` are the initialized panel objects (constructors have already been called from the frame class).

How do I hide the old panel and move to the next panel? Is there an alternative to CardLayout?

Comment: `I am designing a game, hence I do not want to use cardLayout .` - why does that make a difference? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Well, I haven't worked with cardLayout....Is there no other alternative other than cardLayout?

Comment: `Well, I haven't worked with cardLayout....` - so then try it. And you have never used the approach you are trying to do now, since it isn't working. So try CardLayout to find out its benefits and weaknesses. How do you learn about something is you don't try it? Why do you need an alternative when CardLayout does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To change the panel in JFrame use these methods

```
f.setContentPane(gpanel);
f.pack();
```

setContentPane() removes current panel and replaces it with the provided panel.

Comment: Not working. any other alternative/reason behind this?

Comment: Try to use f.pack() after. What layout are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by layout?

Comment: You said you are not using CardLayout. What Layout are you using? Are you using default layout?

Comment: I'm simply using JFrame and JPanel with java swing

Comment: It means you are using default layout and the code in my answer should work, I tested it. I am afraid your select() method is not called at all.